# how to use json rpc with curl on java

Tags: curl, ethereum, json-rpc

i set the private ethereum on my local computer and run as

```
geth --bootnodes="enode://b115ff8b97f67a6bd8294a4ea277930bf7825e755705e809442885aba85e397313e46528fb662a3828cd4356f600c10599b77822ebd192199b6e5b8cfdb530c4@127.0.0.1:30303" --networkid 15 console --datadir "private-data" --rpcport "8545" --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,web3,personal" --rpcaddr 192.168.44.114
```

and then i connect here with the remote computer's blockchain nodes

i want to use ethereum json rpc with curl on java .

i coded it as

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class shell{
public static void makeTran() throws Exception {


String shellcmd = "curl -X POST --data \"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"personal_unlockAccount\",\"params\":[\"0xc7d863e8c89ac4b0336059b4e2cf84a57a6ba7db\", \"1\", 10],\"id\":1}\" http://192.168.44.114:8545/ -H \"Content-Type: application/json\"";
System.out.println(shellcmd);

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shellcmd);

InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

}
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    makeTran();
}
}
```

this must return this line

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":true}
```

but this error is

```
curl -X POST --data "{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","params":["0xc7d863e8c89ac4b0336059b4e2cf84a57a6ba7db", "1", 10],"id":1}" http://192.168.44.114:8545/ -H "Content-Type: application/json"
invalid content type, only application/json is supported
```

here is command

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","params":["0xc7d863e8c89ac4b0336059b4e2cf84a57a6ba7db", "1", 10],"id":1}' http://192.168.44.114:8545/ -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

it can be run on terminal, but its not work on java

if you help me , really appreciate of it !! thanks

Comment: In the command you're running at the terminal, you're using single quotes around the data (so as not to collide with the double quotes in the JSON), but in your Java code, you're just using double quotes in both places.

Comment: As an aside, why are you shelling out to `curl` instead of just making a web request from Java?

Comment: i did both of them . double quotes and single quotes. but it didn't work give same error message. i think there is some library to use json rpc with curl on java . but i can't find it well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting different pieces the way you're doing doesn't work, so try splitting up the command-line arguments yourself. This code works:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
            "curl",
            "-H",
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "--data",
            "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"eth_blockNumber\",\"id\":1}",
            "https://mainnet.infura.io/",
        });

        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

(That said, it's much better to just make the HTTP request from Java. There are plenty of resources available for how to do that.)